# Gps (Location) On and off functionality

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Swift 3.1 in my application. I am new to Swift programming. 
I have to turn GPS on and off (Location) by button clicking from my app.
If I select GPS on, then the screen should navigate to another view controller.

Answer (score 1):

The system automatically handles this and you as a developer don't have direct access to turning the GPS on/off. When you call any methods of `CLLocation` requiring the user's location (such as `CLLocationManager().requestLocation()` or `CLLocationManager().startUpdatingLocation()`), the system will handle the GPS on its own.